# Sorting a list of items into different categories

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Imagine a site that lists different **articles** with different **subjects**, and you as a user can mark your favorite articles to read later. Favorited articles get saved and displayed in your personal little space on this site like this:

**Movies**

- Upcoming summer blockbusters
- Will there never be a end of Superheroes?
- Are romcoms dead?

**Science**

- Bezos or Musk, who will reach Mars first?

**Philosophy**

- How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real?

Etc, etc.

I have saved each article in the database with the following fields:

```
{
  articleName: "Upcoming summer blockbusters",
  subject: "Movies",
  link: //link to the article
}
```

Then when a user favorites one I simply duplicate it into his own collection in the database.

Then comes the problems...

I could iterate through his articles and print them out on his user page like so:

```
<ul>
  {{#each articles}}
    <heading>{{subject}}</heading> //how do I avoid duplicates?
    <li>{{articleName}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This, however, would duplicate the subjects that are shared across multiple articles.

I could iterate through the subjects only (making them into an array that checks for duplicates, for instance) and print them out:

```
<ul>
  {{#each subjects}}
    <heading>{{this}}</heading>
    <li>{{../articleName}}</li> //how do I print the correct one?
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But this way would be completely broken, since the articles wouldn't show up under the correct subject headings...

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think you should store favorite articles only, the way *you* did. It will be way simpler to handle cases like article deletions. Just parse the articles in a helper function, and you should get the same result:

```
favArticlesBySubjects: function () {
    var favArticles = Meteor.user().profile.favArticles;

    var articlesBySubject = [];
    favArticles.forEach(function (article) {
      var index = _.findIndex(articlesBySubject, function (obj) {
          return obj.subject === article.subject;
      });
      if (index < 0)
        articlesBySubject.push({subject: article.subject, articles:[article]});
      else
        articlesBySubject[index].articles.push(article);
    };
    return articlesBySubject;
}
```

This way, you can display your favorite articles using :

```
{{#each favArticlesBySubjects}}
  <heading>{{subject}}</heading>
  <ul>
  {{#each articles}}
    <li>{{articleName}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Would this know which articles go with which subject? Edit: Oh, I think I get it now. Gonna try it out.

Comment: All right, cool, thanks for editing to something better. :) Am I correct in thinking that this method would make it a rather difficult situation if more fields were added onto each article, like `tags` or whatnot, since it's hardcoded which fields get duplicated instead of simply all of them?

Comment: Misunderstood the code on a first glance, now I realize it copies the object in its entirety into `articles`. Nice!

Comment: Yeah, Best would maybe be to keep only an array of article IDs in `profile.favArticles` and in the first line, fetching them from the Collection using `var favArticles = Articles.find({_id: {$in:Meteor.user().profile.favArticles}}).fetch();` That way you always get your full, up-to-date articles. You may not have to fetch them, which would be better, but I cannot find evidence of `cursor.forEach` not being asynchronous... You should try!

Comment: By the way, I had to install `alethes:lodash` since _.findIndex isn't added in the verison of Underscore used by Meteor. All it takes is installing it and using `lodash` instead of `_`. (In case anyone wonders).